# Count Columns query with between specific time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-query-builder

There are two tables, named as **exchanges table** and **finaltrades table**.

Exchanges table has START_TIME field (with format : 00:00:00).

Another **finaltrades** table has **exchange_id**.

I want to count entries only which come between start_time to start_time+1hrs from final trades table. ***FOR EXAMPLE:*** If start_time has 09:15:00, then count between 09:15:00 to 10:15:00 records only.

```
$Count_Trades = FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
                             ->whereColumn('start_time', '+', 01:00:00)
                             ->count();
```

How can i correct this code by relationship?

[Exchnages table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fubNY.jpg)

[finaltrade table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuZI3.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "between start_time to start_time+1hrs from final trades"? Does `finaltrades` also have a `start_time` column?

Comment: finaltrade has not start_time but, i want to make relationship to exchanges table which has start_time, but **finaltrade table has exchange_id**. I have also added example for you. @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: Please add sample date for both tables and the expected result.

Comment: I have added screenshot of both tables @JonasStaudenmeir

Comment: What result do you expect from this data? Do you want to count trades or exchanges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define a relationship between FinalTrade Model and Exchanges Model.

This defines the relationship in FinalTrade Model.

```
public function exchanges(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\EXCHANGE_MODEL_NAME', 'id', 'exchange_id');
}
```

you can find more details on relationships [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

Now you can find your  records using this query

```
$countTrades = App\FinalTrade::where('user_id', '=', $user_id)->exchanges()
    ->where('start_time', '>=', $your_desired_time)->where('start_time' , '<=' , strtotime($your_desired_time) + 60*60)->count();
```

Comment: i want to add 1hrs plus into start_time. FOR EXAMPLE: If start_time has 09:15:00, then count between 09:15:00 to 10:15:00 records only... if start_time is 7:00:00 in exchange table then, count entry 7:00:00 to 8:00:00 @Masoud Haghbin